# Is it possible to switch transformations on and off via binding in xaml?

Tags: xaml, binding

I want to activate transformations via checkboxes.

In my sample I have two checkboxes, which should swap the text in a label in x or y direction respectively.

Is this possible without code behind?

Here is my xaml so far:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfVideoTest.InversionTestWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="InversionTestWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<DockPanel>
    <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" IsChecked="{Binding InvertX}">Invert X</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" IsChecked="{Binding InvertY}">Invert Y</CheckBox>
    <Label Content="Text to invert" FontSize="40" x:Name="TextToInvert">
        <Label.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <!-- transformations to swap in x direction -->
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"  />
                <TranslateTransform X="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=TextToInvert}" />
                <!-- transformations to swap in y direction -->
                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" />
                <TranslateTransform Y="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=TextToInvert}" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Label.RenderTransform>
    </Label>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to use a [Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) or a [MultiConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx).  Yes, it is code, but it's the orderly way code is added to bindings in WPF.  Conceptually, you have a situation where you want the value applied to a transform to be dependent on some other value, and the transform classes themselves don't have that functionality.

This is what the converter might look like.  It expects three values where the first is a bool.

```
public class TernaryConditionalMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length >= 3 && values[0] is bool)
        {
            return (bool)values[0] ? values[1] : values[2];
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```
<ScaleTransform>
    <ScaleTransform.ScaleX>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TernaryConditionalConverter}">
            <Binding Path="InvertX" />
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource PositiveOne}" />
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource NegativeOne}" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </ScaleTransform.ScaleX>
</ScaleTransform>
```

where PositiveOne and NegativeOne have been defined as resources somewhere such as:

```
<sys:Double x:Key="PositiveOne">1</sys:Double>
```

Comment: I get "System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='1' MultiBindingExpression:target element is 'ScaleTransform' (HashCode=43184669); target property is 'ScaleX' (type 'Double')" with this version. 1.0 doesn't work either. So how can I give this converter a correct double value for the second and third binding?

Comment: Never mind, I found it. Just using a StaticResource for the double helps. Anyway for other reasons (incorrect updating of the binding) I ended up with a converter which gives me the complete transformation according to InvertX and InvertY.

Comment: yes, i'll edit the response to have some static resources for the numbers.  thanks for pointing that out.